# Android kitkat - AppCompat: Doesn't load fragments in my FrameLayout container.(Using a Navigation drawer)

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-appcompat

I have implemented a DrawerLayout with Material Design, using AppCompat and it's working ok. The problem is when I try to load a fragment in the container never appear.. and I don't know why.

Below is my activity class

```
public class MyActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private Toolbar toolbar;
private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;
private ListView leftDrawerList;
private ArrayAdapter<String> navigationDrawerAdapter;
private String[] leftSliderData = {"Estaciones", "Favorito", "Contacta"};
private int mCurrentSelectedPosition = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
    nitView();
    if (toolbar != null) {
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }
    initDrawer();
}

private void nitView() {
    leftDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
    navigationDrawerAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>( MyActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, leftSliderData);
    leftDrawerList.setAdapter(navigationDrawerAdapter);
    leftDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Log.e("TEST", position + "");

            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

            Fragment fragment = new Fragment();

            switch(position) {
                case 0:
                    fragment = new Estacion();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    fragment = new Favorito();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    fragment = new Contacta();
                    break;
            }

            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, fragment)
                    .commit();

        }
    });
}

private void initDrawer() {

    drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);

        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);

        }
    };
    drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(drawerToggle);
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    drawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    drawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

}

my xml layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<include layout="@layout/toolbar" />


<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- The main content view -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- activity view -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:text="Activity Content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- navigation drawer -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_gravity="left|start"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:divider="#eee"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your main content view of drawer must be one `ViewGroup` so you must put all your views as children of one viewgroup so put

```
<!-- The main content view -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

as a child of

```
 <!-- activity view -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:text="Activity Content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: so..how should looks my layout?¿ I have tried adding the container in different places and doesn't work :s

Comment: I do not know how your layout should look like. this is your project All I can tell you is what your problem is and how you can solve it.